# Saving data from a modelform Django

Tags: python, django, validation, modelform

Now heads up! I am fresh noob off the NOOB-BUS from NOOBSVILLE!

So i am workin on a form to load up information and edit that form information and im in a headache. so i am using:

Django: 1.8
Pyhton: 3.5.1
backend is sqlite

I am using a form.ModelForm to load information into but when it comes to saving this is where i am stuck. the documentation is very confusing should i use all or just one clean.

this is the forms.py

```
    class EditContact(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:

    model = Contact
    #the list of all fields

    exclude = ['date_modified']


    def clean(self):
        if self.date_of_entry is None:
            print("looking to see what works")
            self.date_of_entry = datetime.date.today()
            return


    def clean_ContactID(self):
        #see this line below this comment i dunno what it does 
        ContactID= self.cleaned_data.get('ContactID')
        print ("cleaning it")
        # i also dont know what validation code suppose to look like
        # i cant find any working examples of how to clean data
        return ContactID
```

now there are mainly more def clean_methods but i think what i want to use is clean which should use all but in my view.

this is in view.py

```
def saveContactInfo (request):

    #this part i get 
    if  request.user.is_authenticated():

        ContactID= request.POST['ContactID']

        a = ListofContacts.objects.get(ContactID=ContactID)


        f = EditContact(request.POST,instance=a)       

        print("plz work!")
        if f.is_valid():
            f.save() 
            return render (request,"Contactmanager/editContact.html",   {'contactID': contactID})
        else:
            return HttpResponse("something isnt savin")

    else:
        return HttpResponse("Hello, you shouldnt ")
```

and this is model.py

```
 def clean(self):

    if self.ConactID is None:
        raise  ValidationError(_('ContactID  cant be NULL!'))

    if self.date_of_entry is None:
        print("think it might call here first?")
        self.date_of_entry = datetime.date.today()
        print ( self.date_of_entry  )

    if self.modified_by is not None:
        self.modified_by="darnellefornow"
        print(self.modified_by )

    if self.entered_by  is not None:
        self.entered_by = "darnellefornow"
        print(self.entered_by )
        ContactID = self.cleaned_data.get('ContactID')

    return
```

now above the model has the fields and the types which all have blank = true and null = true except for the excluded field date_of_entry

and ive gotten to find out that when calling is_valid() in views it calls the models.clean() but it fails to save!!! and i dont know why! i dont know how to do the validation. i would like to know the process and what is required and even an example of form validation a field.

Comment: I really can't understand what you're asking here. If you don't have any custom validation to do on the ContactID field, why are you defining `clean_ContactID()`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: to be honest, i dont know i was following a tutorial and attempting it with my personal project. so what you are saying is just use clean()?
ok i will but it is still failing and i dont know why

Comment: Ok guys i found the solution to my headache one of my fields for was a dateime and i was entering the date in the wrong format. 
so it was expecting "08/16/2016" and i was entering "2016/16/08"

that was causing it to fail. ( the validation )
so for people in the future! watch the way you entered the data into your forms. ESPCIALLY DATES!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're wanting info/answers on a couple of things here, looking at your code comments. Hopefully this helps:

1) You only need to use the clean_FIELDNAME functions if you need to handle something custom specifically for that field. The [Django docs show this as an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute):

```
def clean_recipients(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['recipients']
    if "fred@example.com" not in data:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You have forgotten about Fred!")

    # Always return the cleaned data, whether you have changed it or
    # not.
    return data
```

So in that block, they are checking to see if the email list provided contains a particular email.

2) That also shows another question you asked in your comments about how to handle the validation. You'll see in that snippet above, you could raise a forms.ValidationError. This is discussed more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/

So, if an error is raised in any of those clean_ methods or in the main clean method, the form.is_valid() will be false.

Does that help?

Comment: ok so i should use clean() to clean all got it!
also a side question it added the clean method after i did a migrate and it failed to update the migration would that cause any error in cleaning?



also i am using modelform so is clean() would work on it as well right?

also anyway i can get the system to print out why its failing to edit my contacts?

and help with validation would be nice
like self.cleaned_data.get['contactID']
im asking for alot i know im just confused

Comment: Sure, so migrating only affects the database and updates it based your model changes. I don't think it would have any direct effect on the form clean results unless your model changes are causing validations to fail due to fields be non-nullable or empty. To see why the validation is failing, either try debugging and stepping through the "if condition" that checks f.is_valid(), or printing out to the console with print(f.errors), or displaying in your template the field errors for your user (which you will likely end up doing anyway).

Comment: Check out the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#using-forms-to-validate-data  and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates for more info on those topics

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!
you helped me understand the clean() and validation alot better
i solved it by removing all clean() and by noticing that i was entering the date for my datetimefield wrong 
which now is working i can edit data easliy

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. If my answer was good enough, please feel free to accept it.